# MySQL User Defined Variables Returns wrong result when used with COUNT

Tags: mysql, variables, count, defined

I want to find the number of registered users for a particular year grouped by month.
Below is the query

```
set @numberOfUsers := 0; 
SELECT month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) as month, count(u.id) as monthlyusers, 
(@numberOfUsers := @numberOfUsers + count(u.id)) as totalUsers 
FROM user u 
where year(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) = '2016' 
group by month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate));
```

However, I'm not getting the right result for the totalUsers, it is not adding the result of the previous rows.

```
month  |  monthlyUsers  |  totalUsers
10     |       1        |      1
11     |       3        |      3
```

The totalUsers value in the 11th month should have been 4. Not sure what is wrong in the query.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embeed your `GROUP BY` query in a subquery to compute your running total on definitive results and not while the counts are still "being computed" :

```
set @numberOfUsers := 0; 
SELECT T.*, (@numberOfUsers := @numberOfUsers + T.monthlyusers) as totalUsers 
FROM  
(
    SELECT month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) as month, count(u.id) as monthlyusers
    FROM user u 
    where year(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) = '2016' 
    group by month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate))
) T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the following: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

Following code should work as a solution (working with subqueries):

```
SELECT month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) as month, 
       count(u.id) as monthlyusers, 
       (select count(*) from user USER where year(USER.createdDate)='2016' and month(USER.createdDate)<=month(u.createdDate)) as totalUsers
FROM user u 
where year(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) = '2016' 
group by month(from_unixtime(u.createdDate));
```